# How can I sort a .txt file by two columns?

Tags: sed, awk, sort

```
Feb  7  domainserver dovecot[37495]: auth(default): od(tjones): lookup failed for user: tjones
```

Above is a sample output of what I'd like to sort.  I'd like to sort by date on the first column, but also by `tjones` on the right, which would be the user.

Basically, I want all instances of `tjones` grouped together, but sorted by date.  I really have no idea what command to use in order to do this, or if I need to use the awk command to rearrange columns.

There are obviously more users than `tjones`, so I'd just like to sort by those two columns

I tried the following, but it brought up an error "sort: multi-character tab `\t'"

```
sort -t '\t' -k1,1 -k5,5n auth_2014uniq.txt > auth_2014uniqtest
```

Answer (score 2):

`sort` allows sorting by particular fields with the [`-k` option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html):

```
sort -k11 -k1,2 data
```

will sort first by field 11 (username) and then by fields 1 and 2 together (date). Note that **order is important** here: it sorts by the first `-k` option first, and uses the next to break ties (and so on).

This is very dependent on the exact output you have there - each sequence of spaces is a field separator, so "lookup failed for" is three different fields.

The edit makes it look like your real data has fields that are tab-separated, although I can't figure out where the tabs are in that case. If so, you need to provide a literal tab as the argument to `-t` - `sort` doesn't understand escapes, and your shell likely doesn't expand `\t` either. Either press <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to write a literal tab character in there, or make one to substitute in: something like `"$(echo -ne '\t')"` is one option. If this is the case, substitute the appropriate field numbers in.

`-k5,5n` is a numeric sort on field 5 only - since none of your data is numeric that looks like a mistake.

---

GNU `sort` and some others include [a `-M` month](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) sort extension which you can use to put months in order. This may or may not be available to you; it is also in [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sort&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+9.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) and [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sort.1.html), but not the [other](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/sort.1) [BSDs](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sort%201%20NetBSD-current) and not commercial Unices. If it is available, `-k1,1M -k2,2n` will sort dates by correct month/day order. Note that it is also dependent on your locale: if your log file and your environment use a different localisation, this won't work. Without this, they will be grouped by month and sorted by date within each month correctly.

Comment: `-k1,2M` does the month sort properly - if `-t` is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/\(.*user: \)\([^ ]*\)$/\2 \1\2/p' <<\DATA |\
sort -t' ' -k1,1 -k2,3M |\
sed 's/[^ ]* //'
Feb  7  domainserver dovecot[37495]: auth(default): od(tjones): lookup failed for user: tjones
Feb  8  domainserver dovecot[37495]: auth(default): od(tjones): lookup failed for user: tjones
Feb  5  domainserver dovecot[37495]: auth(default): od(lbones): lookup failed for user: lbones                                                        
Jan  7  domainserver dovecot[37495]: auth(default): od(chaz): lookup failed for user: chaz                                                            
Mar  7  domainserver dovecot[37495]: auth(default): od(lbones): lookup failed for user: lbones                                                        
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Jan  7  domainserver dovecot[37495]: auth(default): od(chaz): lookup failed for user: chaz
Feb  5  domainserver dovecot[37495]: auth(default): od(lbones): lookup failed for user: lbones
Mar  7  domainserver dovecot[37495]: auth(default): od(lbones): lookup failed for user: lbones
Feb  7  domainserver dovecot[37495]: auth(default): od(tjones): lookup failed for user: tjones
Feb  8  domainserver dovecot[37495]: auth(default): od(tjones): lookup failed for user: tjones
```

This prunes the data first, by only selecting lines that contain the string *user:* and copying the following field to the head of the line. So, given the following data:

```
*CRUFT*user: nospaces$
```

Where `$` represents the end of the line, the first thing `sed` does is:

```
nospaces *CRUFT*user: nospaces$
```

...copy *nospaces* to the head of the line. This is a common practice in these sorts of operations, because often even a variation of 1 or 2 in the number of fields in any of the lines can drastically affect the `sort`. It is far better to copy the important fields to the start of the line in order to `sort` *only* on those. In any case, that is what occurs here.

So `sed` passes its edited data over the `|pipe` to `sort`, which sorts first on the first field - the username - and next by `MONTH` on a `-k`ey combining both the second and third fields. The result is all lines are grouped by username and each grouping is sorted by date.

Last `sort` hands its data *back* to `sed` over another `|pipe` and `sed` strips the first field of the line - which is only there because it copied it there in the first place.